# How to keep the graph form when adding new arrows?

Tags: graphviz

I have a graph like this:

[image]

**Question 1:** Is there a way to align the two columns horizontally in the top?

If I want to have an arrow `a5 -> a1`, then the graph would be:

[image]

**Question 2:** Is there a way to keep the graph as clean as before?

Here is the code:

```
digraph {
    rankdir="LR";
// overlap=false;
    nodesep="0.2";
    ranksep="0.4";
    fontsize = 25
    labelloc="t";
    fontname="Lato";
    node [ shape="plaintext" style="filled, rounded" fontname="Lato" margin=0.2 ]
    edge [ fontname="Lato" color="#2B303A" ]
    
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        label = "Column 1";
        fontsize = 20
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        a1
        a2
        a3
        a4
        a5
        
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [style=filled];
        color=blue
        label = "Column 2";
        fontsize = 20
        // labeljust=r
        // labelloc=b
        b1
        b2
        b3
        b4
    }

    a1 -> b1
    b1 -> a2
    a2 -> b2
    b2 -> a3
    a3 -> b3
    b3 -> a4
    a4 -> b4
    b4 -> a5
    a5 -> a1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two minor steps are needed:

(1) Put all `a` nodes in the same rank. If you don't, `graphviz` establishes a hierarchical relationship between `a1` and `a5`, that's what your graph shows.

(2) Add some extra weight to the edge between `a1` and `b1`, to keep it straight.

```
digraph {
    rankdir="LR";
// overlap=false;
    nodesep="0.2";
    ranksep="0.4";
    fontsize = 25
    labelloc="t";
    fontname="Lato";
    node [ shape="plaintext" style="filled, rounded" fontname="Lato" margin=0.2 ]
    edge [ fontname="Lato" color="#2B303A" ]
    
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        label = "Column 1";
        fontsize = 20
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        {rank = same; a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 }        // !!!
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [style=filled];
        color=blue
        label = "Column 2";
        fontsize = 20
        // labeljust=r
        // labelloc=b
        b1
        b2
        b3
        b4
    }

    a1 -> b1[ weight = 10 ];        // !!!
    b1 -> a2
    a2 -> b2
    b2 -> a3
    a3 -> b3
    b3 -> a4
    a4 -> b4
    b4 -> a5
    a5 -> a1
}
```

now produces

[image]

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to force node `an` always align with node `bn`? I try copying `[ weight = 10 ]` to `a2 -> b2`, `a3 -> b3` and so forth, but it doesn't work. (In my real case texts in the nodes vary by length, so the heights of the nodes vary also)

Comment: ohh nevermind. I try `[ weight = 1000 ]` for the most misaligned nodes. The nodes don't horizontally align at the top as I expect, but the result is still tidy

Comment: You can align nodes `an` with nodes `bn` by using empty nodes to fill the difference. But that's a lot of manual work and different from case to case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go about this with the two following changes:

- Use `constraint=false` in order to not have the edge from `a5` to `a1` mess up the graph
- use the `group` attribute to suggest straight edges between nodes (same attribute value for nodes that should be placed in a straight line when connected with an edge)

  ```
  digraph {
    rankdir="LR";
  // overlap=false;
    nodesep="0.2";
    ranksep="0.4";
    fontsize = 25
    labelloc="t";
    fontname="Lato";
    node [ shape="plaintext" style="filled, rounded" fontname="Lato" margin=0.2 ]
    edge [ fontname="Lato" color="#2B303A" ]

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        label = "Column 1";
        fontsize = 20
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        a1 [group=1]
        a2
        a3
        a4
        a5

    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [style=filled];
        color=blue
        label = "Column 2";
        fontsize = 20
        // labeljust=r
        // labelloc=b
        b1 [group=1]
        b2
        b3
        b4
    }

    a1 -> b1
    b1 -> a2
    a2 -> b2
    b2 -> a3
    a3 -> b3
    b3 -> a4
    a4 -> b4
    b4 -> a5
    a5 -> a1 [constraint=false]
  }
  ```

[image: graphviz output]